# If $u$ is $BV$ then $\operatorname{curl} Du = 0$ in the sense of distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u\in BV(\mathbb{R}^N; \mathbb{R}^M)$. How does one prove that $$\operatorname{curl} Du = 0$$ holds in the sense of distributions?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by curl and $D$ here, but leaving that aside, the identity (for smooth functions) just follows from the fact that mixed partial derivatives can be taken in any order, which of course holds for distributions as well.

Comment: @ChristianRemling You're completely right. Thank you.

Comment: @Riku : Note that \operatorname{} has context-dependent spacing and \mathrm{} does not. Hence my edit.

Comment: @ChristianRemling If you write down that in an answer. I'd gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Riku: Thanks, but this remark doesn't seem to have enough substance for an answer, I'll leave it up as a comment.